# Cast de Byte[] a String y de String a Bytes

Tags: c#, cast, casting

Explico, tengo una consulta en SQL que me devuelve a veces Int's y a veces Doubles

```
+--------+-----------+
| Algo   | Resultado |
+--------+-----------+
| Algo1  |   521     |
+--------+-----------+
| Algo2  |   5.12    |
+--------+-----------+
| Algo3  |   0       |
+--------+-----------+
```

Aclaro desde ya que la consulta no la puedo cambiar.

Lo que antes hacía era.

```
Byte[] val;
while(dr.read()){
  val = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dr.GetValue(2).ToString());
   objeto.setValor(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(val));

 }
```

La otra clase:

```
 class Objeto
 {
     private double valor;
     //otros atributos

    public void setValor(String valor)
    {
        this.valor = Double.Parse(valor, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
```

Y me solía funcionar, pero ahora no sé por qué motivo me dice

> **System.FormatException**: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.'

La consulta me devuelve dos tipos de datos por que es algo del estilo:

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM Tabla
UNION
SELECT AVG(valores)
FROM Tabla
```

**Aclaro de nuevo que no puedo modificarla**

Comment: porque usas byte[] si a la siguiente linea lo casteas a string? digo si usas directamente la funcion setValor pasandole el string del valor, funcionaria el parse.

Comment: Byte[] utilizo por que la consulta devuelve ``INT`` y ``Double``

Comment: un campo -> 1 tipo de dato, a no mas que uses el sql_variant como tipo de dato de esa columna? mas alla de eso, si haces directamente  objeto.setValor(dr.GetValue(2).ToString()); deberia funcionar

Comment: La verdad no se entiendo el uso de Byte y porque diferencias doublé de int si los vas a meter en la misma variable, comprueba primero el valor que te llega si usa punto o coma sin espacios, si es necesario pásalo a .toString() y conviértelo directamente a doble

Comment: La consulta en sí es un count(*), pero es un alias. Está formada por: SELECT una cosa, 'un alias', count(*)/Avg(valores) en el último caso, no la puedo modificar por lo que...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece ser que la excepción

> **System.FormatException**: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.'

era causada por `dr.getValue(2)` al pasarlo a String me devolvía un String `"System.Byte[]"` cuando recogía la información de la **BBDD**.

Lo he solucionado haciendo un `dr.getString(2)` directamente y parece que funciona bien.